# Le « camouflet » est-il synonyme de « soufflet » et ce qu'en dit Victor Hugo ?

Tags: sens, synonymes, argot, littérature

> Qu’est-ce que recevoir un soufflet ? La métaphore banale répond :
> *C’est voir trente-six chandelles*. Ici l’argot intervient, et reprend : *Chandelle, camoufle*. Sur ce, le langage usuel donne au soufflet
> pour synonyme *camouflet*. Ainsi, par une sorte de pénétration de bas
> en haut, la métaphore, cette trajectoire incalculable, aidant, l’argot
> monte de la caverne à l’académie; et Poulailler disant : *J’allume ma
> camoufle*, fait écrire à Voltaire : *Langleviel La Beaumelle mérite
> cent camouflets*.
>
> — Victor Hugo, [*Les Misérables*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k411299f/f408.image.r), 1862

Le mot [camouflet](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/camouflet) est-il usuellement (hier, aujourd'hui) employé comme synonyme de [soufflet](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/soufflet) ; est-ce que c'est dans ce sens-là que l'emploie Voltaire cité par Hugo ? Peut-on éclairer la lecture du passage avec la *chandelle* et *camoufle*, ce jeu entre la métaphore et l'argot dont parle Victor Hugo ?

Answer (score 2):

> Le mot camouflet est-il usuellement (hier, aujourd'hui) employé comme synonyme de soufflet ?

Hier sans doute mais aujourd'hui non. *(Donner/recevoir un) soufflet* n'est plus utilisé et camouflet ne l'est plus qu'au sens figuré, en général dans une expression du type *c'est un camouflet pour untel, il a essuyé un camouflet* où il ne s'agit jamais physiquement d'une gifle, mais  d'une vexation, une humiliation brusque dont est victime la personne qui reçoit ce camouflet.
La gifle est une pratique qui a heureusement considérablement régressé ces derniers temps.

> Est-ce que c'est dans ce sens-là que l'emploie Voltaire cité par Hugo ?

Oui, pour Victor Hugo, il devait bien s'agir d'une gifle.

> Peut-on éclairer la lecture du passage avec la chandelle et camoufle, ce jeu entre la métaphore et l'argot dont parle Victor Hugo ?

Une gifle fait voir trente-six chandelles. En argot, chandelle se disait *camoufle*, qui a donné *camouflet* pour signifier *gifle*.

Les cheminements étymologiques montrent des variations importantes de sens:

chault mouflet: fumée (chaud) que l'on souffle (moufle: joues gonflées) au visage de quelqu'un.
camouflet: bouffée de fumée →  camoufler: cacher derrière un écran de fumée
camouflet: chandelier
camoufle: bougie
camouflet: gifle, vexation

On trouve *chault mouflet* rimant avec *soufflet* dans cet extrait de *Mystère*, dans le [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/mofle) (Ancien français):

> Qui dormira, qu'on le réveille
> Ou qu'on lui donne un chault moufflet
> Ou hardiement un grand soufflet.

Comment: Merci ! Ah je croyais que la chandelle était le sujet du verbe camoufler dans la citation et donc je n'avais pas allumé. Plus généralement tu l'as vu je posais la question parce que je pensais que camouflet signifiait normalement gifle. En fait je pensais que c'était encore plus soutenu que soufflet. Soutenu++ hahaha.